# Split number by decimal and return back as 2 separate elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split

Here is a tricky task. I have price list as this :

```
<span class="price">10.99€/span>
<span class="price">1.99€/span>
```

I need to transform this into this

```
<span class="price">10<span class="decimal">.99</span></span>
<span class="price">1<span class="decimal">.99</span></span>
```

Here is how I approach this so far

```
$(".price").each(function() {
    var PriceArray = ($(".price").text());
    var re = /\s*€\s*/
    var PriceArraySplit = PriceArray.split(re) // I remove Euro sign
});
```

Further, as I understand, I need to split each number by decimal and store those in array and then replace values using new values from that array.

That's where my brain got overflowed.

Comment: _"as 2 separate elements"_ - Where by "separate" you mean "nested"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it:

```
 $(".price").each(function(){
      var $this = $(this),
          PriceArray = $this.text().split('.');
      $this.html(PriceArray [0]+'<span class="decimal">.'+PriceArray [1].replace('€','')+'</span>');
    })
```

Comment: How I can modify this code to split not only by "." but also by ",". I am trying $this.text().split('.') || $this.text().split(','), but that doens't work. Is there an easy solution, or I need to write a if/else function to check if there is a "." or "," in a string

Comment: split accept regex as argument: PriceArray = $this.text().split(/[.,]/);   http://jsfiddle.net/ACyXQ/

Answer (score 1):

Here's the <s>first</s> *second* way that came to mind:

```
$("span.price").html(function(i,oldHtml) {
   return oldHtml.replace(/(\.\d+)€?/,'<span class="decimal">$1</span>');    
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tAHW3/1/

Should be reasonably self-evident; if not, reading some doco for [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml) and [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [JS regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) should help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) functions as such:

```
$(".price").each(function() {
    var s = $(this).text().split(".");
    $(this).html(s[0] + '<span class="decimal">.' +  s[1].replace('€','') + '</span>');
});
```

Here's the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mihirgokani007/PQrNg/).